# Light bodies at high speeds behave like heavy objects when recorded by a high speed camera

Tags: collision, speed

This is potentially a very dumb question, but recently I was looking at some slow motion footage of bullets hitting stuff and I realized something interesting.

One of the clips showed two metal objects (approximately bullet sized) colliding in midair at high speeds. They didn't go directly at each other. In fact their approach was something like this

```
------>
      7
     /
    /
   /
  /
```

So as they approached eachother "slowly", when they finally connected the contact surface practically exploded. In any case, the deformation was much larger than what I expected considering the difference vector of their velocities was quite small (they were traveling at the same speeds, but slightly different angles).

This reminded me of scenes in sci-fy movies where two large spaceships collide in space but at low speeds. Since their mass is very high, the lack of their speed doesn't matter. They rip through each other.

Related to this, imagine you grab an ant or some small insect and throw it at the wall. It might grab the wall or fall off, but it won't be hurt. I imagine if you recorded it with a high speed camera you could apply the same principle.

Like bullets, it behaves like a heavy object but since you can't throw it nowhere near as fast as a bullet, it's "heavyness" isn't enough because the camera "slows it down" enough so he doesn't get hurt.

My question is, what's the correlation between those three factors? The mass, the speed of the object and the speed of the camera.
Could we potentially make small models of spaceships, throw them at each other very fast so when you record them in slow motion it looks like big spaceships colliding slowly?

Comment: Sounds more like you were fooled by a combination of slo-mo and point of view.  Since we don't know the actual speed or composition of the two objects, the elasticity of the collision (i.e. how much they don't deform) can't be predicted

Comment: But that's kind of my point. It fooled me because it looks very similar.

Comment: This is currently done regularly in Hollywood. Remember the [White House getting blown up](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z3qu-sCei3U) in the movie *Independence Day*? That was a 1/12 scale model that was built solely to be blown up. *Star Wars* did the same thing for [Battle of Yavin](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_of_Yavin).